# select where field has more than 2 non duplicated records sql

Tags: mysql

This should be pretty easy but I am just not able to figure this one out.

Got a table with customers order information. There is a field within this table called customers_email_address and customers_id along with a number of other non-essential fields. I need to locate distinct records where the entries in the customers_email_address field are different but unique to the same customers_id. In other words, I need to find out what customers have changed their email address in their account since their account's inception so I can update my email advertising program with their new email address. Something I didn't think of when the site was designed!

Maybe an example would be:

```
customers_ID    customers_email_address
1               joeschome@hotmail.com
2               frankj@hotmail.com
1               joeschome@hotmail.com
2               frankj@hotmail.com
1               joeschome@yahoo.com
2               frankj@yahoo.com
3               janefr@live.com
3               janefr@live.com
3               janefr@live.com
```

result of query should look like this:

```
customers_id    customers_email_address
1               joeschome@hotmail.com
1               joeschome@yahoo.com
2               frankj@hotmail.com
2               frankj@yahoo.com
```

Only returning where the customers_email_address field has multiple non-duplicate records but same customer_id

Perhaps something better would be like this:

```
customers_id    customers_email_address1        customers_email_address2
1               joeschome@hotmail.com           joeschome@yahoo.com
2               frankj@hotmail.com      frankj@yahoo.com
```

I hope this makes sense. If you have a better idea, please feel free to chime in.

Anyway, thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Please show your current query and table structure. Prerably through sqlfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** You can do it like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.customers_id, o.customers_email_address
  FROM orders o JOIN
(
  SELECT customers_id
    FROM orders
   GROUP BY customers_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT customers_email_address) > 1
) q
    ON o.customers_id = q.customers_id
 ORDER BY o.customers_id;
```

Output:

```
| CUSTOMERS_ID | CUSTOMERS_EMAIL_ADDRESS |
|--------------|-------------------------|
|            1 |     joeschome@yahoo.com |
|            1 |   joeschome@hotmail.com |
|            2 |        frankj@yahoo.com |
|            2 |      frankj@hotmail.com |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f4da/2)** demo

Comment: Think you may have hit the nail on the head peterm! You're awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Will do. Gotta wait a few it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

This will return out two columns customers_email_address1 and customers_email_address2 and fast because it can use an covering index

```
SELECT 
 orders1.customers_ID
, orders1.customers_email_address "customers_email_address1"
, orders2.customers_email_address "customers_email_address2"
FROM 
 orders orders1

INNER JOIN 
 orders orders2

ON
 orders1.customers_ID = orders2.customers_ID
AND
  orders1.customers_email_address != orders2.customers_email_address

GROUP BY
 orders1.customers_ID

;
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1c8e/43

Or if you need an denormalized list (maybe easy when updating from application code)  you can use this and this should also be very fast even on large tables because an covering index is used

```
  SELECT
    customers_id
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT customers_email_address SEPARATOR '|') as emails
   FROM orders
   GROUP BY customers_id 
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT customers_email_address) > 1
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1c8e/41